# How to increment a variable that is also date onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

So far, I have it so that the first and last day of the current week is displayed. I want to make it so that when the user clicks on the button, the first and last dates for the next week is shown. I have tried incrementing,  but as you can see in the code below, it does not seem to work. Is incrementing the right method to achieve this feat, and, if it is, how should I tweak my code to make it work?

```js
//DISPLAY CURRENT DATE
var d = new Date();
var m1 = d.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var first = d.getDate() - d.getDay();
var last = first + 6; 

var year = d.getUTCFullYear(); 
     
document.getElementById("currMonth1").innerHTML = m1;
document.getElementById("currDay1").innerHTML = first;
document.getElementById("currMonth2").innerHTML = m1;
document.getElementById("currDay2").innerHTML = last;

document.getElementById("currYear").innerHTML = year;

//WEEK AFTER
function nextWeek() {
var d = new Date();

var first = d.getDate() - d.getDay();
var last = first + 6; 

var newFirst = ++x;
var newLast = ++x;
var x = 7;

document.getElementById("currDay1").innerHTML = newFirst;
document.getElementById("currDay2").innerHTML = newLast;
}
```

```css
.number{
 display: inline-block;
}

h2 {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="nextWeek()" class="arrow" value="&rarr;"><br>

<h1 class="number" id="currMonth1"></h1>
   <h1 class="number">/</h1>
   <h1 class="number" id="currDay1">
</h1>
<h1 class="number">&rarr;</h1>
   <h1 class="number" id="currMonth2">
</h1>
   <h1 class="number">/</h1>
   <h1 class="number" id="currDay2">
<br>
   <h2 id="currYear"></h2>
```

**EDIT:** I managed to find the solution. Instead of just using ++x, I used [insert variable here]+= x and [insert variable here]-= x. Thanks for the feedback to all those who have given a response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` gets undefined in `nextWeek` function,
Define `x` outside of `nextWeek` function

```
var x = 7;
//WEEK AFTER
function nextWeek() {

var d = new Date();

var first = d.getDate() - d.getDay();
var last = first + 6; 


var newFirst = ++x;
var newLast = ++x;

document.getElementById("currDay1").innerHTML = newFirst;
document.getElementById("currDay2").innerHTML = newLast;
}
```

here is demo https://jsbin.com/cobelol/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a little ordering problem. You should reorder you code lines

```
var newFirst = ++x;
var newLast = ++x;
var x = 7;
```

The order should be like.

```
var d = new Date();
var first = d.getDate() - d.getDay();
var last = first + 6; 
var x = 7;
var newFirst = first+x;
var newLast = last+x;

document.getElementById("currDay1").innerHTML = newFirst;
document.getElementById("currDay2").innerHTML = newLast;
```

Answer (score 0):

Made few changes to your code so month doesn't remain the same when `nextWeek` function runs.

```js
//DISPLAY CURRENT DATE
var d = new Date();
var m1 = d.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var first = d.getDate() - d.getDay();
var last = first + 6;

var year = d.getUTCFullYear();

document.getElementById("currMonth1").innerHTML = m1;
document.getElementById("currDay1").innerHTML = first;
document.getElementById("currMonth2").innerHTML = m1;
document.getElementById("currDay2").innerHTML = last;

document.getElementById("currYear").innerHTML = year;

//WEEK AFTER
function nextWeek() {
  var date = new Date();
  var numberOfDaysToAdd = 7;
  
  // set date for next week first day and month
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
  var nextWeekFirstDay = date.getDate();
  var nextWeekFirstDayMonth = date.getUTCMonth() + 1;
  
  // set date for next week last day and month
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 6);
  var nextWeekLastDay = date.getDate();
  var nextWeekLastDayMonth = date.getUTCMonth() + 1;

  document.getElementById("currDay1").innerHTML = nextWeekFirstDay;
  document.getElementById("currMonth1").innerHTML = nextWeekFirstDayMonth;
  
  document.getElementById("currDay2").innerHTML = nextWeekLastDay;
  document.getElementById("currMonth2").innerHTML = nextWeekLastDayMonth;
}
```

```css
.number {
  display: inline-block;
}

h2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="nextWeek()" class="arrow" value="&rarr;"><br>

<h1 class="number" id="currMonth1"></h1>
<h1 class="number">/</h1>
<h1 class="number" id="currDay1">
</h1>
<h1 class="number">&rarr;</h1>
<h1 class="number" id="currMonth2">
</h1>
<h1 class="number">/</h1>
<h1 class="number" id="currDay2">
<br>
   <h2 id="currYear"></h2>
```